# How to select only info with a certain date to appear on the DataGridView C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, datagridview

So my issue is the following: I have a form with 2 datetimepickers, that will give the start and the end of the period I want.

Per example: Start: 05/12/2016
             End: 07/12/16

And I want info from 05/12/2016, 06/12/2016, 07/12/2016

The info is saved in a text file (dados.txt) and the saved values are displayed in this particular order(Name, Group, Value, Date) on a DataGridView.

In the text file:

Paul    Superfluos      234       09/12/2016

John    Superfluos     3242      10/12/2016

Alex  Vestuario      4000      12/12/2016

Mike  Diversos       5000      11/12/2016

In conclusion, if I select the start from 10/12/2016 to 12/12/2016, i will get the info of John, Alex and Mike displayed and the Paul info will not be shown.

Here is the code i use to save the data of my first DataGridView:

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("dados.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                writer.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t");
            }
            writer.WriteLine("");





        }
        writer.Close();
```

And the code I use to display all the info in the other DataGridView:

```
 public class User
{

    public string Designação { get; set; }
    public string Grupo { get; set; }

    public string Valor { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }


    public static List<User> LoadUserListFromFile(string path)
    {
        var users = new List<User>();

        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
        {
            var columns = line.Split('\t');
            users.Add(new User
            {
                Designação = columns[0],
                Grupo = columns[1],
                Valor = columns[2],
                Data = columns[3]

            }
            );
        }

        return users;
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me, Thanks.

Comment: you could serialize a list<user> so as not to save everything as string.  dates for instance dont act like dates when stored as string

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Also: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: Hello, sorry for my noob error, because I am new to these questions, already edited right, TaW :D